# How to remove Time Machine designation on my external hard drive

Tags: time-machine, external-disk, spotlight

My external hard drive has the Time Machine icon on it but I am not using it for backup. I am using it as a regular hard drive. I tried to include it in Spotlight for indexing but it won't allow me to as it is a Time Machine.

How do I remove the designation? I have already checked the Time Machine on System Preferences and it is stated that it is not using any hard drive for backup and yet my external hard disk still has the Time Machine icon preventing me from indexing it.

Comment: Is it being used by another Mac? Has it been used as a TM backup at any point in the past?

Comment: My mac is connected with another mac. I have check that mac time machine preferences and it is not being use as a time machine.